# .Net compact framework SqlClient exception

Tags: c#, exception, compact-framework, windows-ce, sqlclient

I develop for Windows CE 5.0 device and I'm trying to connect to remote SQL Server. But if I use command with parameters I get exception:

```
{System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: SqlException
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, TdsParserState state)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, TdsParserState state)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior run, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
at Test.MainForm.TestConnection()
...
}
```

Code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);  
conn.Open();  
SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();  
cmd.CommandText = "select * from table_name where id = @id";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("id", 1));
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

And without adding parameters to command it works fine. Please suggest me what could be the reason?
(I'm using VS2008, .net compact framework 3.5)

Comment: What is the exception message exactly? And looks like you forget to use `)` and `@` in your adding parameter line like `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", 1));` Or could be a type of course..

Comment: @SonerGönül, Yes, sorry, missed bracket was just a typo in post, but not `@`. The same code without `@` works in .Net Framework 3.5 project (not Compact), so that's why I was confused. Thanks a lot)

Comment: By the way, it is full exception message: Message="SqlException" and stack trace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

put '@' before parameter name like

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@id", 1));
```